# Grab process information about high process usage

Tags: process, high-load

I'm looking to grab process information about processes that are using over a certain CPU limit.

Ex:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def get_processes_over_usage(cpu_usage):

    #Find the processes.

    return processes
```

Specifically, I'm looking for the executable and the username of the process.

Thanks!

Here is the answer, I just can't post it yet:
This doesn't exactly conform to the requirements, but it's close enough.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import commands

def get_processes():

    output = commands.getoutput('/usr/bin/top  -n 1')

    lines = output.split('\n')

    header = ['PID', 'USER', 'PR', 'NI', 'VIRT', 'RES', 'SHR', 'S', '%CPU', '%MEM', 'TIME+', 'COMMAND']

    header_found = False
    processes = []

    for line in lines:  
        data = line.split()
        if(data):
            data.pop()
        if(data):
            data.pop(0)

        if(header_found):
            processes.append(dict(zip(header, data)))

        if(data == header):
            header_found = True

    return processes
```